# The cardinality of a countable union of sets with cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$ has cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove that: union of countably many sets with cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$ is $\mathfrak{c}$. I have tried to use the Cantor-Bernstein theorem, and here is what I have so far:

To prove the result, we need to show that

1. $\bigl\vert \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_{i} \bigl\vert \leq \mathfrak{c}$
2. $\bigl\vert \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_{i} \bigl\vert \geq \mathfrak{c}$

Since $\vert A_i \vert = \mathfrak{c}$, it is obvious that (2) is true. Hence, the only result that really needs to be proven is (1), meaning that we need to construct an injective function from the uion to $\mathbb{R}$, which is what I struggle with.

The only other idea I had is to proceed by contradiction:

Suppose that the cardinality of the union is not $\mathfrak{c}$. Then the union has a cardinality less than $\mathfrak{c}$, but a subset that has cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If it's "countably", shouldn't you be looking at $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_i$?

Comment: Hint: intervals have cardinality $\frak c$.

Comment: Is this true in ZF for an arbitrary countably infinite collection of sets with cardinality of the continuum, or does this require axiom of (countable) choice? I believe it's the latter, just like in absence of choice it may be the case that continuum is a union of countably many countable sets.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that $\Bbb R = \bigcup_{n \in Z} [n,n+1)$, so a set of size $\mathfrak{c}$ is a disjoint union of countably many sets of size $\mathfrak{c}$...